# Laravel Relationship method must return an object of type Relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've been scouring google trying to figure out a solution. I'm getting the:

```
ErrorException in Model.php line 2755: Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

error when I try to go to my posts index page, and a just can't figure out where it's coming from. I can get to the page when I redirect from creating a post, but after that I get the error. Supposedly it's supposed to come from not returning a relationship, but here's my relationships and code:

Post

```
public function category() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

User

```
public function roles() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withTimestamps();
}
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'user_id');
}
```

Role

```
 public function users() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Category

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'category_id');
}
```

index.blade.php

```html
@extends('app')

@section('content')
 <h1>Posts</h1>

 @if (Auth::check()) 
  @if (Auth::user()->isAdmin())
   <a href="/post/create">Create a Post</a>
  @endif
 @endif
 @foreach ($posts as $post)
  @include('includes.post', ['post' => $post, 'link' => true])
 @endforeach
@stop
```

and post.blade.php

```html
<div class="post">
 <div class="div">
  <div class="postCategory">
  
  </div>
  @if($link)
   <a href="/post/{{ $post->id }}"><h2>{{ $post->title }}</h2></a>
  @else
   <h2>{{ $post->title }}</h2>
  @endif
  <p>{!! $post->body !!}</p>
  <p>{{ $post->category->name }}</p>
  <p>Posted by <a href="/user/{{ $post->user->username }}">{{ $post->user->username }}</a> at {{ $post->created_at }}</p>
  
  @if(Auth::check())
   @if($post->user->username == Auth::user()->username || Auth::user()->isAdmin)
    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'delete', 'route' => ['post.destroy', $post->id]]) !!}
     <input type="submit" value="Delete Post" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"></input>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
   @endif
  @endif
  
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an inverted '\' in the Role model. Is it that maybe?

Comment: Nah, I just switched it and it's still the same. The full error is: Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation (View: C:\wamp\www\installation01\resources\views\includes\post.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp\www\installation01\resources\views\includes\post.blade.php)

Comment: Ok. I think this exception is thrown when you want to access a relationship as a field (e.g. $post->category) but then the category() function is not well defined. Try commenting out the lines in blade where you do that. (The ones with $post->category->name or $post->user->username)

Comment: Before opening the form in post.blade, the last check you do is: Auth::user()->isAdmin. In the other file, you check: Auth::user()->isAdmin(), note the (). Check what happens if you add () to the one that doesn't have them

Comment: That was it! What a stupid mistake. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before opening the form in post.blade, the last check you do is:

```
Auth::user()->isAdmin
```

In the other file, you check:

```
Auth::user()->isAdmin() //note the ()
```

Add them where missing